# Class composition - Call outer method from inner class

Tags: php, oop, composition

I have a outer class that has another class as a member ( following the principle composition over inheritance ). Now I need to call a method of the outer class from the class within.

```
class Outer
{
    var $inner;
    __construct(Inner $inner) {
        $this->inner = $inner;
    }
    function outerMethod();
}
class Inner
{
    function innerMethod(){
// here I need to call outerMethod()
    }
}
```

I see as a solution to add a reference in Outer::__construct :

```
$this->inner->outer = $this;
```

This allows me to call the outer method like this in Inner::innerMethod :

```
$this->outer->outerMethod();
```

Is this a good solution or is there a better alternative ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason for inner class calling the outer? Why not something like calling outer method with inner as parameter, so as not to create circular dependancies?

Comment: The reason is : the inner class is a specialisation of the outer. There are several possible classes that implement an InnerInterface. The outer class contains the invariable methods and the inner class contains the specialisation specific methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best idea would be to include the outer class as a member variable of the inner.

E.g.

```
class Inner
{
    private $outer;
    function __construct(Outer $outer) {
        $this->outer= $outer;
    }
    function innerMethod(){
// here I need to call outerMethod()
       $this->outer->outerMethod();
    }
}
```

If it's not possible to construct the inner with the outer initially, you can put a `setOuter` method on the inner and call it when you pass it into the `Outer`.

E.g.

```
class Outer
{
    private $inner;
    function __construct(Inner $inner) {
        $inner->setOuter( $this );
        $this->inner = $inner;
    }
    function outerMethod();
}

class Inner
{
    private $outer;
    function setOuter(Outer $outer) {
        $this->outer= $outer;
    }
    function innerMethod(){
// here I need to call outerMethod()
       $this->outer->outerMethod();
    }
}
```

NOTE: `var` as a specification as a membed variable type is deprecated.  Use `public`, `protected` or `private` instead.  Advice - err on the side of private unless you have reasons not to.